# system.security.NoAccessException when trying to save

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a big confusion here.

I have a visual force page with a custom controller. It has a save button that calls the save() action in the custom controller.

- Custom controller has "without sharing"
- My understanding is all Apex runs in System mode and does not respect user permissions.

I created a profile (Say Profile_1) with "Read only" access to an object (Say Object_1). If my understanding is right about Apex, the save() method should successfully insert the object for any user (even if he is from Profile_1_. But it did not. It failed for user from Profile_1 with the following error as banner message

> system.security.NoAccessException: Create access denied for Sales_Certificate_Signature__c

Once I gave "create" permission for Object_1 on Profile_1, it inserted successfully. What am I understanding wrong here? Without sharing should not make any difference here as its role and sharing rules related and not profile related.

Comment: Another detail is that my "save" is not in a try catch. So if its an exception, it should redirect me to the ugly page. But instead it shows a nice banner message!!

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks moved my question over there